# How to motivate freshman students towards automata groups?

Tags: automata, cellular-automata, group-theory

I'm a new professor and working at a computer science college. I'm going to be responsible for giving a one-hour lecture to motivate my students to study automata groups.

I'm very experienced as a teacher and I think that I'm a really good speaker, but no idea about how to make these topics friendly and attractive for students who are just coming from high school.

I wonder how to find references and if you have any success experience on that to share with me.

Our ultimate goal is to make students interested in our research lab in which I'm a new member as well.

Comment: Welcome! Since it asks about how to motivate students to study something, it would be useful to describe the expected course outline for automata groups that these freshmen would take, thank you.

Comment: What are automata groups?  I have never heard that phrase before.  Can you give a few examples?  Even better, describe what topics they will study, as Kenneth Kho suggests.